# Is there a way to make a makefile autodownload another makefile?

Tags: makefile, build-automation

i know it is possible to execute standard rules on a makefile by simply including them like

```
hi:; echo hello

include hi
```

but there is some way, by doing this, to fetch an external input like a ftp server or, lets say, the aws s3 to fetch a "newborn" makefile and then include it to the project? in runtime?
like

```
include https://s3.bucket.domain.com/newmk.mk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned there's no way to include a URL.  However, you can do something almost as good with GNU make's [auto-re-make feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html).

To do this, include a local file you download *and* create a rule that knows how to download it:

```
include newmk.mk

newmk.mk:
        wget https://s3.bucket.domain.com/newmk.mk -O $@
```

In this situation, if (and only if) `newmk.mk` doesn't exist, then the recipe will be invoked, the file will be downloaded, then make will re-exec itself to read that file.

Comment: i've done that way, just didn't knew that it would only download the new file if the old is not present.
Thanks! i'll get a way to work around it

Comment: So you want to download the file every time you run make even if it already exists?  You didn't say that in your question.  I interpreted _a "newborn" file_ to mean that you only wanted to create it if it didn't exist.

Comment: Yeah the purpose of that would be that the file would update itself before executing any command. i got that workaround by adding a selfdestroy rule and including it by the end of the file. worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The `make` utility has no built-in download support (not even GNU's make which sometimes seems to have the kitchen sink thrown in), but because it can run arbitrary commands, you can fake it up

The simplest case is a fragment like

```
your_primary_target: newmk.mk

#...
WGET=wget
WGET_FLAGS=-q

newmk.mk: 
    $(WGET) $(WGET_FLAGS) https://s3.bucket.domain.com/newmk.mk
#...
```

which will attempt to download the file only if no such file exists.

The main difficulty here is that your users may need to edit the makefile to specify the command-line downloader they have (perhaps `curl` instead of `wget`), or it set any flags their network environment requires.

---

To make the download unconditional  use a unbuildable, non-existent target

```
WGET=wget
WGET_FLAGS=-1

newmk.mk: ALWAYS
    $(WGET) $(WGET_FLAGS) https://s3.bucket.domain.com/newmk.mk

# Here "ALWAYS" is *not* the name of a file existing in the file-system
ALWAYS:
```

(or there are games you can play with `.PHONY` in GNU-make).